# Ubuntu 20.04 AMD GPU with Intel process stuck on 1024x768(4:3) Resolution

Tags: drivers, 20.04, dpkg

I've installed Ubuntu with single boot option. I wasn't able to install Ubuntu straight away, I've had to use safe graphics mode option to install Ubuntu 20.04.After successful installation, I was presented with a black screen. Then I started Ubuntu again in recovery mode and tried to install AMD latest Ubuntu 20.04 drivers and I got the below error at around 97%. Command used to run AMD driver is below:

`./amdgpu-install -y`

Error Message I got is this

```
Building for 5.4.0-47-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-47-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-47-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.0.15-1098277/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.0.15-1098277); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up g++-9 (9.3.0-10ubuntu2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failur
e.
  Setting up g++ (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++ to provide /usr/bin/c++ (c++) in auto mode
Setting up build-essential (12.8ubuntu1) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib32 (20.20-1098277) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried the above method twice and have uninstalled the drivers. The below result is after uninstalling amdgpu driver from AMD site.

The interesting point is the result from the command:

```
sudo lshw -c video
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Tonga XT / Amethyst XT [Radeon R9 380X / R9 M295X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: f1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:dfe00000-dfe3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried the latest version till date and that is 17-Sep-2020 which is present on AMD site and the AMD driver version is 20.30 and problem still exists. The good news is it didn't gave any error and installed it. One positive sign there, it may have helped someone with this update, but not me. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried to install 20.45, for 5700XT on Ubuntu 20.04, had the exact same problem

Answer (score 1):

My situation is a little different since I'm using a headless server for crypto mining, but I was getting the same error message regarding amdgpu-dkms. I did manage to get 20.45 driver working on Ubuntu Server 20.04 using the following steps:

`./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=legacy,pal,rocr --headless -y`

omit --headless if using desktop gui.  errors will still be present

get mainline kernel update script

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh`

install kernel update script

`sudo install ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh /usr/local/bin/`

run kernel update script

`sudo ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -i`

script will display most current kernel available and ask for confirmation to install. In my case it was 5.10.1-051001-generic

after reboot, mining software still didn't work.
amdgpu didn't show up in lsmod so I did:

`sudo modprobe amdgpu`

and suddenly my mining software worked. haven't tried rebooting because I'm just so relieved that it started working.

I also installed kernel 5.6.19 at one point and ran `update-initramfs -u`

I don't think that had any effect but just mentioning it for completeness.

Comment: it may be crush os

Answer (score 0):

Based on the AMD notes https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45. Please try to downgrade the kernel to 5.4.0-55.61. Well, in your case, you may need to upgrade the kernel. You may need to use `update-alternatives` to select a newer version of `g++`

A new kernel `linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic` just released, maybe you could try that kernel to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you red5marauder...After going through at least 30 sites and reinstalling ubuntu 20.04 5 times, following all the instructions only this option worked. I haven't restarted the system yet worried that I will get a black screen.

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 and installed amd drivers (20.45) downloaded from the amd site. I had done this before and my system booted up with a black screen. What worked primarily was the options for installing ./amgdpu-pro-install -y --opencl=legacy,rocm --headless

After this option the system started but the screen was very laggy when the mouse cursor moved. I was just happy that the system started. Still sudo lshw -C display generated everything except the recognition of an AMD card.

I just tried the options given above and magically it worked. The kernel update worked. Cannot say how thankful I am.

Answer (score 0):

you can also install the driver without dkms with the command

```
./amdgpu-install --no-dkms
# or
./amdgpu-install --opencl=pal,legacy --no-dkms
```

I've tested this, and have been using this for two months now.